# GoogleSignIn.null: DEVELOPER_ERROR when logging in with Google on Android

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I can correctly open the login screen, choose my Google account, but after choosing my Google account I get:

> GoogleSignIn.null: DEVELOPER_ERROR

I unrestricted my API key to make sure it wasn't because of the hash, and I've looked at other DEVELOPER_ERROR posts but they seem unrelated.

[image]

It's a react native app (not expo) using the expo package for google sign in:

```js
  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({ clientId: undefined })
      await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync()
      const { type, user } = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync()

      if (type === "success") {
        const encodedToken = encodeURIComponent(user.auth.accessToken)
        setUri(`${BASE_URL}/auth/google_oauth2/native?token=${encodedToken}`)
      } else {
        alert(`Google login: type ${type}`)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(`Google login error: ${e.message}`)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this error on Android (not iOS) and to fix it I had to do 2 things.

On the [Google console Credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) I initially created the OAuth 2.0 Client ID with the 'Google Certificate Fingerprint' (ie SHA-1) I got from Expo (using `expo fetch:android:hashes`).

Since I'm building locally (with `npx react-native run-android`) I changed the SHA-1 value on the Google console to the SHA-1 of my local debug.keystore. You can use `keytool -list -v -keystore ./android/app/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android` to get the SHA-1.

(If you are using Firebase instead of Google Cloud then change the SHA-1 value there.)

In addition, add this SHA-1 from the debug.keystore to your `app.json` file:

```
{
    "expo": {
        "android": {
            "config": {
                "googleSignIn": {
                    "certificateHash": "<Your SHA-1 certificate fingerprint>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This configuration option is not mentioned at all on [the Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/) for `GoogleSignIn`. I found this in various GitHub issues:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3439#issuecomment-463625673

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8927#issuecomment-650199762

If you don't have the 'android' and 'ios' folders yet (ie your still on a managed Expo project), you'll need to eject: either run `expo eject` or `expo run:android` and `expo run:android`.

Comment: it is 2023 now. I was able to see the consent screen after clicking the button. However getting the info back, it doesnt work and it is still giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not use the command generated by Google for the SHA-1 and instead use the simpler command that asks for the password:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore your.keystore -alias youralias
```

Then in https://console.firebase.google.com, Project Settings (gear icon in the upper left) -> Your Apps -> SHA certificate fingerprints, add the SHA-1